# Read lines until certain string and remove it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a small python code, that opens a file, read it until certain string, print it.

The code is below:

```
filename = 'teste.txt'

with open(filename, 'r') as input:
   for line in input:
     print(line)
     if '**==**' in line:
       break
```

After the print, I need to erase it from the file, basically removing the lines until `**==**`, leaving the other lines untouched.

I've tried:

```
search = '**==**'
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
  print(line)
  if search in line:
      break

if i < len(lines) - 1:
    with open('teste.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(lines[i + 1:]))
```

But each time that I run the code, the "next line block" starts to have a lot of spaces between then.

The file can have between 6 - 10 MB

Any suggestions on how I can do it?

Comment: Is the file small enough to read it once and process it?

Comment: @emremrah The file is close to 6-10MB

Comment: @PaulMark--your issue of extra blank line was caused by lines already containing '\n' at the end of each line.  '\n'.join(...) inserted an additional line between each line.  You needed to perform a `f.writelines(lines[i+1:])` to write the sequence of lines see [writelines](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_writelines.htm)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```py
with open('teste.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if search in line:
        lines = lines[i + 1:]
        break

with open('teste.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `lines = f.readlines()` in the second line of code?

Comment: Not actually. `readlines` will cause the `lines` to be a list. No need to. Just read entire  (if it's small enough to process) as string, to the job, and re-write it.

Comment: @emremrah Sorry but didn't work, I've add the ```Print(lines) ``` doesn't show anything

Comment: @emremrah--unless lines in a list, your for loop is not reading a line at a time.  That's why the corrections about using `lines = f.readlines()` from others.

Comment: Sorry, but it's only removing the **==**, not all lines before it. And when I pint the lines var, I got all lines in text less the **==**

Comment: Can you share a part of actual file? Maybe there is something different.